# Embedding $\beta\mathbb{N}$ into a product of Cantor sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, gn.general-topology, semigroups-and-monoids, ultrafilters, compactifications

Let us consider $\beta\mathbb{N}$, the [Stone-Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of the natural numbers (where we do not take $0$ to be a natural number, so the only idempotent elements are nonprincipal ultrafilters), with the usual topology and the semigroup structure inherited (extended) from the naturals.

Also, let $\mathcal{C}$ be the (topological) Cantor set, and $\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{C}$ be the space of all functions from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{C}$, endowed with the Tychonoff product topology (or the topology of pointwise convergence) and the semigroup structure of composition of functions.

Do you know of any characterisation of the possible topological embeddings of $\beta\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{C}$? Are there any concrete (and non-trivial) examples? Are any of these embeddings also homomorphisms?

Comment: @JosephVanName, I think the OP is interested in homomorphisms (preserving semigroup structure) rather than homeomorphisms.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega The question ends with "Are any of these embeddings also homomorphisms?" So I think the earlier parts of the question were intended to be about arbitrary, not necessarily homomorphic, embeddings.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I know, I was referring to Joseph´s comment about $2^{2^\omega}$ not being homeomorphic to $\beta\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, precisely, this is why I emphasized 'topological embeddings' in the first question. I wonder if any such exist to begin with...

Comment: A topological embedding of $\beta\mathbb N$ into $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ since the latter space contains the Cantor cube of weight continuum, which contains all Tychonoff spaces of weight $\le \mathfrak c$ (in particular, it contains a topological copy of $\beta\mathbb N$). So, the question concerns (topological) semigroup embeddings.

Comment: Continuous homomorphisms from $h:\beta\mathcal N\to S$ to any compact semigroups $S$ are uniquely determined by the image $s=h(1)$ of the unit $1\in\mathcal N$. For any ultrafilter $p$ the image $h(p)$ is just the $p$-limit of the sequence $(s^n)_{n=1}^\infty$. So, the question is to find $s\in S$ such that the continuous extension $\bar h:\beta\mathbb N\to S$ of the map $h:n\mapsto s^n$, is an (injective) semigroup homomorphism. It seems that $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ is a compact left-topological semigroup, so there is a non-zero probability that this approach can work.

Comment: What happens if we take for the image $h(1)$ a minimal homeomorphism on the Cantor set $\mathcal C$. Is the continuous extension $\bar h:\beta\mathbb N\to\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ of the map $n\mapsto s^n$, a semigroup homomorphism?

Comment: @TarasBanakh Thank you for your comments! Your first one answers that there definitely is a topological embedding of $\beta\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{C}$. The question of `how many' there are, though, remains...

I'll think about your second point - yes, it sounds like that approach should work. To clarify: by minimal homeomorphism $f$, you mean continuous $f$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ does not contain any nontrivial closed $f$-invariant subsets?

Comment: @Simon_Peterson Indeed, by a minimal homeomorphism I understand exactly what you wrote. It seems that your question is related to problems considered in Chapter 19 (called "Relation with topological dynamics") of the book "Algebra in the Stone-Cech compactification" by Hindman and Strauss.

Comment: By Theorem 19.11 in Hindman-Strauss book, for any continuous self-map $f:X\to X$ of a compact Hausdorff space the unique continuous map $h:\beta\mathbb N\to X^X$ with $h(n)=f^n$ for all $n$ is a semigroup homomorphism. So, the question is to find $f$ making $h$ is injective. It is certainly is not injective if the set $\{f^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $X^X$ and $X$ is Dugundji (e.g. metrizable) compact. It may happen that no continuous $f$ making $h$ injective exists at all. Then one should try non-continuous generator $f$. But in this case it is not clear why $h$ should be a homomorphism.